# Bitmap image is getting merged to previously uploaded image

Tags: java, php, android, bitmap, image-upload

Hi eveyone I am uploading image to server but i am facing weird issue .
Suppose I selected one image and uploaded it then again I am selecting other image and uploading but issue is that previously uploaded image is uploaded with increase in size.I tried bitmap recycle() but its not working .I am also selected image to imageview it is showing correct image but while uploading it is uploading previous image with increase in size.
Below is my code

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetImageFromGalleryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);

        UploadImageOnServerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        ShowSelectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageName);

        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        GetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showPictureDialog();


            }
        });


        uploadImageOnServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetImageNameFromEditText = imageName.getText().toString();

                uploadImageToServer();

            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        5);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Photo Gallery",
                "Camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }
    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    FixBitmap =MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI));
                    // String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
                    UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
            UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //  saveImage(thumbnail);
            //Toast.makeText(ShadiRegistrationPart5.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void uploadImageToServer(){

        FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);

        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        class asyncTaskUploadClass extends asyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

                HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://techvengerlabs.tk/new/upload-image-to-server.php", HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        asyncTaskUploadClass asyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new asyncTaskUploadClass();
        asyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
        FixBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public class imageProcessClass{

        public String imageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

                bufferedWriter.flush();

                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String RC2;

                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilder.append("=");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is the second time you ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504930/facing-issue-while-uploading-image-previously-selected-image-is-getting-uploaded And again you posted all kind of irrelevant code like requesting permissions and so. Please remove all irrelevant code.

Comment: And many variable names are still starting with a capital. Please write decent java code. Let them begin lowercase. (You can see their colors: blue instead of black).